# npm install of a local package has missing files

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-install

I have a project with this format

```
├── functions/
│   ├── src
│   ├── lib
│   ├── package.json
├── shared/
│   ├── src
│   |   ├── index.ts
|   |   ├── interfaces.ts
|   |   └── validator_classes.ts
│   ├── lib
│   |   ├── index.js
|   |   ├── interfaces.js
|   |   └── validator_classes.js
│   └── package.json
└── frontend/
    . . .
```

shared has interfaces and classes shared between the frontend and the functions.

I do `npm build` in functions and then `npm install shared` in functions or frontend the `node_modules/shared` section looks like this

```
└── shared/
    ├── src
    |   ├── index.ts
    |   ├── interfaces.ts
    |   └── validator_classes.ts
    └── lib
        └── index.js
```

and is missing the `interfaces.js` and `validator_classes.js` files from the `lib`. the `src` is the same

here is the package.json of shared

```
{
  "name": "shared",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc -d"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "class-validator": "^0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

and here is the ts config of shared

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "outDir": "lib/",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts",
    "src/formatter_interfaces.ts",
    "src/validator_classes.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/__tests__"
  ]
}
```

## EDIT:

I tested it by changing the main property of the package.json in shared to `/lib/validator_classes.js` and now it only installs that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to have added a

```
"files": [
    "lib"
]
```

to the package.json